# Codename one. Cant add webview from Gui Builder

Tags: webview, codenameone

I am creating an app for IOS, I opne the theme res on the editor, add a new GUI element, and when i try to add a Web View, nothing happened, the other components like maps or similar can be added. Only happen with the Web View

There is other way??

Comment: Are you using the new Gui Builder or old one?

Comment: I am not sure. i am believe is the new , version 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find the way to do it on code

```
 protected void beforeWebcams(Form f) {
    WebBrowser browser=new WebBrowser();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
   }
```

now I will open a new question, i need to display an HTML code inside this webbrowser

Comment: That way isn't correct... You need to use `BorderLayout` not `FlowLayout` and use `addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);`. Otherwise the browser will take up its preferred size which might be 0 on the device or too big for the screen. The 0 size can happen because the HTML might take a while to parse.